# Iphone development Certificate issue

Tags: iphone, certificate, submission

Hi I have created a Development certificate using the key chain procedure explained on apple website.

since i have finished my app now when i try to create a distribution certificate with the same key that i used for development portal for some reason dist certificate is not hooking to the key chain like the development cert. however i have added it manually by selecting file>import items. now when i submit my app to app store i get an email saying Invalid Binary and they are saying the certificates are not valid. I have tried numerous times with no result.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When the distribution certificate was generated, was it generated on the same machine that you are attempting to install it on? If not, you need to.

Comment: This may be a stupid question but are you code signing your app with the developer certificate and signing the bundle with the distribution certificate.

Comment: @Mark yes it was on same machine and i only have 1 imac.

Comment: @Abizern when we select Device and Debug it will point to Developer certifiacte and when we change to Device and Distribution it will point to Distribution certificate. thats how i did.

Answer (score 0):

OK that was stupid of me for being lazy and not reading apple website to. my app status is finally Wauting for review now. all i did was deleted all the certificatesand started step by step from apple distribution certification creation and submission and it all was dead seamlesss!.. Thank God my app is all over from my end it took ages!!!!!!!!!!!!